# website domain htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have a domain with host www.mydomainhost.com .
Now i got another domain named www.newdomain.com

I want, when user connects to www.newdomain.com, the url must remain www.newdomain.com but i want to use the host of www.mydomainhost.com.

It is like sharing the host with 2 domains.

My host ip is static (we can redirect)

it is said that i have to change .htaccess 
But when I searched i saw that .htaccess generally used inside domain name link redirections.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: htaccess wont help. You need to change the DNS so that newdomain would point to mydomainhost.com. Just have in mind that you should avoid content duplication as this is really bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of DNS and only DNS to do it as you require, IF you can manipulate the DNS records it's easy-ish to do. Or else you will need to get the relevant managers of the DNS entries to work together to make sure that newdomain.com points to the IP of domain.com and that the server on which domain.com is configured to accept it.